# TSQL - Using cursor to remove repeating records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursors

everyone!

I have a table that has a couple columns: **Part_No** and **Checksheets**.

Any given Part_No may have multiple checksheets that need to be performed.

I am trying to remove repeating Part_No's, so my spreadsheet will eventually look something like this:

```
Part_No | Checksheet
Part1   | Part1checksheet1
        | Part1checksheet2
        | Part1checksheet3
        | Part1checksheet4
Part2   | Part2checksheet1
        | Part2checksheet2
Part3   | Part3checksheet1
        | Part3checksheet2
        | Part3checksheet3
```

Instead of like this:

```
Part_No | Checksheet
Part1   | Part1checksheet1
Part1   | Part1checksheet2
Part1   | Part1checksheet3
Part1   | Part1checksheet4
Part2   | Part2checksheet1
Part2   | Part2checksheet2
Part3   | Part3checksheet1
Part3   | Part3checksheet2
Part3   | Part3checksheet3
```

I am assuming I would create a variable and use a cursor to go through each row and check the part number, but I am just not sure how to figure this out.

Thanks to anyone that can help!

Comment: That's fine on SQL Server. You may want to do this during the presentation.

Comment: Cursors are rarely a good choice .. what do you mean by "spreadsheet" ? An SQL table should resemble the second example, not the first - are you asking for a SELECT query to produce an output that resembles the first example?

Comment: You can do that with row_number() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: I will be exporting the SQL table to an excel spreadsheet, but was wondering if I could make the table look like the first example before exporting

Comment: You would create a VIEW that SELECTed the data from the table in the desired format rather, than actually modifying the data

Comment: I created a temp table and selecting the data to put into that table, then modifying how I want the data to show up

Comment: If you are not a dba with at least ten years of experience, you should not consider writing a cursor, that's how bad they are.

Comment: What is so bad about using cursors? Not saying that are not bad, I just do not know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a VIEW:

```
create view vw_ForExcel as (
select 
    case when row_number() over (partition by Part_No order by Part_No) = 1 then Part_No else '' end as Part_No,
    Checksheet
from THE_TABLE
)
```

Then export it (or `SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_ForExcel`)

Comment: Er... how are you supposed to order this?  You should include an actual `Part_No` column in the view because you'll need it for an `ORDER BY` clause or, failing that, a `RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Part_No)`.